# Need to created WPF MVVM with three applications in one project

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have created 3 applications in one project. 
In 1st application , I am maintaining the class file , 
In 2nd application , I am maintaining two usercontrol ,In 1st usercontrol one text box and one button and in 2nd usercontrol two textbox and two buttons.
In 3rd application , I am maintaining two windows file to display the user controls.

Now , In 1st usercontrol if i click the button , it should open up a new window and in that 2nd uercontrol should get display. the process method should me maintain in separate class file which i am maintaining in 1st application.

Like wise after the 2nd usercontrol open in that i will be having two buttons one is for submit and another one is for cancel. If i click the cancel button , only that window alone get close . this method also should be maintain in same class file , which i am maintaining in 1st application.

This project as to be created with using of WPF MVVM pattern.
I need to open a new window from the current window
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please tell us, where you are stuck at. Dont hesitate to show some code also

Comment: Please make the question more clear by adding sample code.

Comment: Created a simple one : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7e2unhwceks6of5/WpfMvvm.rar?dl=0